# Android Studio - autocomplete within androidTest/res not working?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

When opening up .xml files under `/src/androidTest/res/` the autocomplete doesn't seem to activate.  (ie. I start typing android:... and usually a menu will popup with completion suggestions)

Is there some setting that doesn't get turned on by default that I'm missing?

Comment: Do you have `unit` tests activated or `androidTest` (instrumentation)?

Comment: I'm able to run the tests if that's what you mean?

Comment: What do you mean "autocomplete" is not work? Are the sourcesets active? Also, yes, can you run tests?

Comment: Meaning, it does nothing in android .xml files that aren't under /src/main, there is no context help from the editor in android studio.  Not sure of the exact correlation you are going for, but the gradle configuration and test builds compile and run fine.

Comment: This leads me back to my first question.

Comment: Try `Build->Clean Project`, then restart the app and lastly remove the project and re-import it again (delete `gradle` and `.idea` directories). I usually solve this bug in the regular, non-test, module.

Comment: as per the question, I have /src/androidTest/ "activated".  I'll try some of the re-import and see where that takes me.